# HttpSecurity Spring Boot configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I need to configure 3 endpoints, 2 with authentication and 1 without. The problem is I'm getting all the endpoints with 401 Unauthorized error.

- `/users` no authentication need
- `/users/1` needs authentication
- `/details/1` needs authentication

I'm using the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And I implemented the class:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                    .password("pwd")
                    .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement you just need simple http configuration where GET users can be accessed by all as public url and other need basic auth..below will work for you.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

    }
```